# Multivariate normal calculation not producing standard normal variables

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, math

This may be more of a math question than numpy, so I'm not sure, this may need to be posted on Cross Validated instead.

### Problem description

I am using numpy's function `np.random.multivariate_normal()` to produce randomized, correlated data.  I want to have 5 correlated variables, *each distributed standard normal*. I believe my covariance matrix is correctly specified, with diagonals equal to 1.0 and the inner values being my desired correlations. The generated data consistently have the correct mean of 0, but the standard deviation is unpredictable.

### Reproducible example

Here is a reproducible code example:

```
# rho = randomizer.config.customers.correlation
rho = np.array([
       [  1.0 , -0.2 ,  0.7 ,  0.1 ,  0.1 ],
       [ -0.2 ,  1.0 ,  0.7 ,  0.5 ,  0.2 ],
       [  0.7 ,  0.7 ,  1.0 ,  0.6 ,  0.5 ],
       [  0.1 ,  0.5 ,  0.6 ,  1.0 ,  0.3 ],
       [  0.1 ,  0.2 ,  0.5 ,  0.3 ,  1.0 ]
])
# rho = np.identity(5)
mu = np.repeat(0, 5)


standard_deviations = []
for i in range(10000):
    np.random.seed()
    sd = np.std(np.random.multivariate_normal(mu, rho, size=1000)[:, 0])
    standard_deviations.append(sd)
    
plt.show(plt.hist(standard_deviations, edgecolor="black", bins=40))
```

This produces this plot:

[image]

The standard deviation is clearly greater than the 1.0 specified in the covariance/correlation matrix.

Is there an obvious explanation for this that I'm missing? I notice that if I use an identity matrix instead of my correlation matrix, the problem goes away:

```
rho = np.identity(5)
mu = np.repeat(0, 5)


standard_deviations = []
for i in range(10000):
    np.random.seed()
    sd = np.std(np.random.multivariate_normal(mu, rho, size=1000)[:, 0])
    standard_deviations.append(sd)
    
plt.show(plt.hist(standard_deviations, edgecolor="black", bins=40))
```

[image]

Really appreciate any help!

Comment: Covariance and correlation are not the same as far as I know. Shouldn't the matrix be squared or something like that?

Comment: The standard deviation of the first plot is ~0.03 to my eye

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the thing causing your problem, but the covariance matrix of a multivariate normal is positive semidefinite, whilst `rho` here has a negative eigenvalue and hence is not.